# ORA 01843: not a valid month

Tags: c#

Estoy realizando un insert a mi base de datos, tengo mis parametros en un array asi como los datos que se  van a estos, en especial y que esta dando problemas es la fecha

```
comando.Parameters.Add(parameters_1[i], lista_2[i]);
```

, en mi base de datos esta como tipo de dato `Date`, este es el resultado que obtengo `07/08/2020 10:38:33 AM`, pero cuando llega el momento de `comando.ExecuteNonQuery();` me manda al catch y me arroja esto

> ORA 01843: not a valid month

De esta manera obtengo el dato:

```
 DateTime fecha = DateTime.Parse(valor);
    var fec = fecha.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    elements[1] = fec;
```

Comment: Ya intentaste haciendo en tu linea de código lo siguiente?
var fec = fecha.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

Comment: si, y esto tambien `var fec = fecha.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: tal vez para que puedan ayudarte mas a fondo podría ser de mucha ayuda mostrar de que forma está tratando de insertar la fecha, al parecer el problema es cuestion de cultura de fecha, y hasta podría ser una configuración de fechas de tu equipo / servidor. Podrías intentar haciendo el ToString  solo: var fec = fecha.ToString();
En el ejemplo que te dí arriba lo que hice fue invertir el mes y el día, espero que hayas intentado cualquiera de todas esas variaciones y que puedas solucionar tu problema, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Para insertar fechas en manejadores SQL, lo más recomendable es pasarla en formato `yyyyMMdd` o `yyyy/MM/dd`

Por el código del error, supongo que se trata de Oracle. Si este es el caso puedes utilizar la función `TO_DATE()` esta función recibe 2 parámetros de tipo string, el primero es la fecha y el segundo es el formato en el que se encuentra la fecha [ver mas](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)

Ten en cuenta que esta es una funcion de Oracle y no de C# así que debes modificar el la instruccion sql con algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
INSERT .... VALUES (..., TO_DATE(@tuParametro, 'MM/dd/yyyy'), ...)
```